# Getting and Display data from Excel file

Tags: android, excel, display

I have an excel file with over 80 rows full of data. In specific columns I have the data that I mention in my code.

I am trying to get these data and then display them in a textView. Unforunately when I run my application I get the following Display:Name: jxl.read.biff.NumberRecord@ce3885a and so on. Can you please help me with that?

`enter code here`public void order(View v){
        try{
        AssetManager am=getAssets();
        InputStream is=am.open("data.xls");
        Workbook wb=Workbook.getWorkbook(is);
        Sheet s=wb.getSheet(0);

```
    EditText num=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.getID);//take input for id
    int row=Integer.parseInt(num.getText().toString()); //i have to get the patient ID from insert

    Cell name=s.getCell(row,6);
    Cell sex=s.getCell(row,7);
    Cell birthdate=s.getCell(row,8);
    Cell age=s.getCell(row,9);

    //display("Name: "+name+"/n");
    //display("Sex: "+sex+"/n");
    //display("Birth Date: "+birthdate+"/n");
    //display("Age: "+age+"/n");

    TextView textView=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_data);
    textView.setTextSize(22);
    textView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    //textView.setTextColor(000000);
    textView.setText("Name: "+name+"\n"+"Sex: "+sex+"\n"+"Birth Date: "+birthdate+"\n"+"Age: "+age);
    }
    catch(Exception e){

    }
}

public void display(String value){
    TextView x=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_data);
    x.setText(value);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result you see is the memory address of the cell. That is because you forgot to get the contents of the cell and you are trying to read the cell itself rather than the contents. You should use [Cell.getContents();](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/resources/javadocs/2_6_10/docs/jxl/Cell.html) to read the contents of a cell into a String:

```
Cell name = s.getCell(row,6);
String nameString = name.getContents();
```